# Run batch file from SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to run batch file from SQL Job without using exec xp_cmdshell.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The typical way is to use a SQL Server Agent Job, *not* `xmp_cmdshell`. What kind of job do you want to run? Why would you want to initiate that from inside the *database*?

Comment: There are different steps of functionality.  For that I have to run some stored procedure which are doing CRUD operation for database. Once these operations completed, I want to execute my application background process. This is dependent on previous steps.

Comment: SQL Server Agent can do that already. SSIS can handle far more complex scenarios, eg branching based on query results.

Comment: If you don't want it in a Agent Job, then you could just use SSIS, and execute the package within SSISDB. If you need it to be parametrised, you can also then easily achieve that; where as "parametrising" an Agent Job is a little more  difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running batch file, i have created power shell and ran it from SQL job. It satisfy my requirement and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a SQL Server Job, otherwise i cannot think of a way you could without xp_cmdshell.
Take a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a123aff-c38b-4c99-9d3a-46a81f75e1f2/stored-procedure-to-call-exe-without-xpcmdshell?forum=transactsql)

Comment: Currently I am using it from  SQL Server Job but using xp_cmdshell. So I don't want to use xp_cmdshell. One more point is, my batch file is situated at another server not on SQL server

Comment: @umesh.chape why are you doing that at all, instead of executing the batch directly? A SQL Server Agent job can have both CMD and Powershell steps. As for "remote execution", that's a *very* important requirement that should be included in the question itself. You should explain *what* that script does too. Perhaps the best option is to use remote powershell execution, perhaps not

Comment: That's exactly what i mean @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: There are different steps of functionality. For that I have to run some stored procedure which are doing CRUD operation for database. Once these operations completed, I want to execute my application background process. This is dependent on previous steps.

Comment: Then you can insert it after the CRUD operations steps with a clause of "if prev step fails do not execute"

Comment: Yes. I have added this as last step of my Job after completion of CRUD operations but currently it is running via xp_cmdshell  i.e. exec xp_cmdshell  "D:\abc.bat".  Now I have moved the .bat file on another server which is not SQL server where the SQL job was hosted.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run batch file from SQL Job without using exec xp_cmdshell.
>   Any idea?

Worth to mention that you can also leverage **SQLCLR**.

Example: [CLR Stored procedure to execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968009/clr-stored-procedure-to-execute-command)

Some other googlable threads:

- [How to execute a DOS command when xp_cmdshell is disabled in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2087/how-to-execute-a-dos-command-when-xpcmdshell-is-disabled-in-sql-server/)
- [Executing an external process() in SQLCLR Project](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5faf47d2-4556-4f37-a2b1-2a2e128acb6b/executing-an-external-process-in-sqlclr-project?forum=sqlnetfx)

Such approach introduces severe risks like memory leaks, crashing of underlying .net app pool etc

Therefore another link: [Security in the CLR World Inside SQL Server](https://www.codemag.com/article/0603031/Security-in-the-CLR-World-Inside-SQL-Server)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like the picture: [like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnMDK.png).

- The drive containing the batch file should be other than the C drive, to avoid trouble.
- Add execute, read and write permissions for the user, which you are using to run the batch file, to get the username run this query: EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami', get the name after the \ sign.  For example "nt service\mssqlserver". Add permission for this user: mssqlserver
- Finally make sure you put the batch file on the same server as where you execute your Job.